# Compare a list of dictionary to list

Tags: python

I'm trying to compare a list of dictionaries to list and if there is a match increment rank. Is there a better way(more efficient way) to do this. My code:

```
requirements = ["JSF","JSP","Spring"]
Employee_records = [{'job_seeker_id': 1, 'skills': ['Spring', 'JSP', 'JSF'], 'experience': '5 years', 'location': 'stockholm', 'rank': 3}, {'job_seeker_id': 2, 'skills': ['Servlets', 'JSP'], 'experience': '2 years', 'location': 'gothenburg', 'rank': 1}, {'job_seeker_id': 3, 'skills': ['JSP'], 'experience': '4 years', 'location': 'lund', 'rank': 1}, {'job_seeker_id': 4, 'skills': ['Servlets'], 'experience': '3 years', 'location': 'malmo', 'rank': 0}, {'job_seeker_id': 5, 'skills': ['Hibernate', 'Servlets'], 'experience': '1 years', 'location': 'stockholm', 'rank': 0}]

for dict_ in Employee_records:
    for elm in dict_["skills"]:
        for skill in requirements:
            if elm == skill:
                dict_["rank"]+=1
```

Comment: You could use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) instead of a list to improve lookup time

Comment: How did you get the `Employee_records` dictionary? Did you read it out of a database? My guess is that the filtering can be done there rather than in your application code. Also, how often do you need to do this? If it's  a batch process that runs a few times a day with a small number of records, then your approach (while not really fast) is sufficient.

Comment: I got the Employee_records from the database but the requirements list will not be static it might change from time to time depending upon the request to the application so I have to perform filtering in the application code itself and this runs for each and every request with a specific requirements list. – @Noufal Ibrahim

Comment: If you have a list of `requirements` in a python list, It'd better to do a query like `select * from users u where user.skill in (list, of, skills, from, application)` or something like that and then process that list. The filtering should be done in the database rather than the application. It doesn't matter  if the list is dynamic. You can pass that to a db query. That's how all database driven applications work. I suspect that you're going about this the wrong way since you're more familiar with python than your db's query language.

Comment: Perhaps if you can tell us what your databases looks like and what kind of db it is, one of us can help you with a query that solves this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for dict_ in Employee_records:
    dict_["rank"] += len(set(dict_["skills"]) & set(requirements)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there are no duplicates in `requirements`, then this:

```py
for skill in requirements:
    if elm == skill:
```

is actually equivalent to:

```py
if elm in requirements:
```

So you can simplify to:

```py
for dict_ in Employee_records:
    for skill in dict_["skills"]:
        if skill in requirements:
            dict_["rank"] += 1
```

---

But, you don't really need to pass through all the `skills` and check if they're in the `requierments`, you can just check the intersection between them:

```py
req = set(requirements)

for emp in Employee_records:
    emp['rank'] += len(set(emp['skills']) & req)
```

You should convert the `list`s to [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set)s for an efficient operation.

Comment: This counts the number of employees whose skills **exactly** match the requirements. The question is about counting the **overlap** between the requirements and the emplyees' skills.

Comment: @retnikt thanks, I didn't notice that and though of the question differently. Updated

Answer (score 0):

Using [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set)s makes the code neater and more pythonic, though there won't be much of a performance change.

```py
requirements = {"jsp", "jsf", "string"}
for employee in employees:
    employee["rank"] += len(set(employee["skills"]) & requirements)
```